# Adding a custom Sort field in Drupal

Tags: entities, views

In our business we assign tasks to users based on the last digit of a company ID. When I created the view for these users, it was simple to create a "Formula" field and use RIGHT(field name, 1) to get this value.

I'd like to make an exposed filter that will allow users to only see companies ending in, say, 5 (for example).

Question: Is using the "Sort" function the best way to do this, or is there another way to add filtering to a table created by a view? It would be wonderful to add text search filters to each column, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Question: How do I create a new field and make it available in the "add field" interface?

Thanks! Rich (who isn't the normal drupal developer and was left to learn on his own)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rich who isn't the normal Drupal developer and was left to learn on his own. Welcome to Drupal.

I've encountered scenarios in which I had an exposed sort with a dropdown list and I needed to remove all the options that didn't fit my pattern. I used a [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) that modified the `'#options` list for the element to `unset()` the items I didn't want to allow the user to select. However, this method doesn't prevent those items from showing when `-All-` is selected, so that may not work if that's an option for your users.

The way you'd add a new field is to [create a custom field handler](https://gist.github.com/juampy72/5816530) but it sounds like what you want might instead be a [custom sort handler](https://drupal.org/node/904334) or a [custom filter handler](https://drupal.org/node/1239866). The three are similar but not identical in their implementation.